# Venmo payment SDK Chaining System

Tags: ios, payment, braintree, venmo

I have installed Venmo and Braintree API integration successfully.
I want to know is there a way to integrate chaining system in that?
Like user can pay some amount to other user which don't have Venmo account and some of the transfer amount will get paid to Merchant as well

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions, please feel free to reach out to [our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Yes, [Braintree's Marketplace product](https://www.braintreepayments.com/marketplace) does exactly that. You can [pay any phone number / email address](https://staging.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/guide/marketplace), even for people who don't have a Venmo account yet:

```
result = Braintree::MerchantAccount.create(
  :individual => {
    :first_name => "Jane",
    :last_name => "Doe",
    :email => "jane@blueladders.com",
    :phone => "5553334444",
    :date_of_birth => "1981-11-19",
    :address => {
      :street_address => "111 Main St",
      :locality => "Chicago",
      :region => "IL",
      :postal_code => "60622"
    }
  },
  :funding => {
    :destination => Braintree::MerchantAccount::FundingDestination::Email,
    :email => "funding@blueladders.com",
  },
  :tos_accepted => true,
  :master_merchant_account_id => "14ladders_marketplace",
  :id => "blue_ladders_store"
)
```

You can take a [service fee](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/transactions/service_fee) on each transaction that will be paid to you:

```
result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
  :merchant_account_id => "blue_ladders_store",
  :amount => "10.00",
  :credit_card => {
    :number => "5105105105105100",
    :expiration_date => "05/2012"
  },
  :service_fee_amount => "1.00"
)
```

Comment: is there is any way we can access user's venmo email address for funding via backend ?

Comment: @Leena I don't understand your question. I suggest you [contact Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).